# The usage of the "to + be + v3"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Eg: Your surgeon should also explain the type of anesthesia ***to be used***.

In the above example, what is the meaning and tense of the "to be used".

Further, please explain to me that there is any omission or contraction in the phrase like participle clauses or relative clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is used to express an intended action. "the type of anaesthesia to be used" effectively means "the type of anaesthesia which the surgeon is going to use". It is sometimes unclear who specifically will be using the object, and this is the main reason for the use of the construction: you don't need to specify a subject.

This construction is simply formed with the infinitive "to be" and a past participle. It is passive in meaning, as are many constructions formed with the verb "to be".

I suppose there could be an omission, with the full sentence being "Your surgeon should also explain the type of anaesthesia **which is** to be used", but I don't think that part is especially common to leave in.